# Google tts api giving me blank mp3

Tags: php, text-to-speech

I'm trying to use google text-to-speech but the service not giving me.
I'm using this url to get mp3 : 
`http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=en&q={$text}`

Service return the error : our client does not have permission to get URL. How can I fix this ?

Comment: how are you trying to get the mp3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `cURL` will avoid some checks:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");

    $text = urlencode('my text');
    $url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=".$text;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $return;
?>
```