# jquery for google tts no voice

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

When I use this code let google_tts speak word voice, the code is ok but have a problem. The word voice must listen http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=dog(word) first then run this code the rusult is OK, but when I won't listen  http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=dog(word) first the code can't speak the word.I reference [Google Translate TTS problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068139/google-translate-tts-problem) ,I want to know the real problem and how to fix it ?

1. In browser Firefox is that better but have above-mentioned problem
2. In IE is audio error: not support file type...
3. In Chorme is no any action,even //translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=dog have no voice

I want to know how to fix let IE and Firefox browser run successful, thank a lot

HTML

```
<form id="say-form">
        <button id="say-button">Say!</button>
        <audio id="audio" preload controls>
            <source id="s1" />
        </audio>
   </form>
```

JQuery

```
 $('#say-form').submit(function(){
        var ar = new Array("dog","egg","what","big")
        var i=0,file = $("#audio")
        console.log(ar[0])
        $("#s1").attr("src", "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q="+ar[0]).detach().appendTo("#audio");
        file[0].load();
        file[0].play();
        i++;
        // when it play end, play next word until ar array it's finish
        file.on( "ended", function(){
            if(i!=ar.length)
            {
                $("#s1").attr("src", "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q="+ar[i]).detach().appendTo("#audio");
                $(this)[0].load();
                $(this)[0].play();
                i++;
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you use Php?

```
$text = urlencode('my text');
$url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=".$text;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $return;
```

?>
like this [Google tts api giving me blank mp3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669075/google-tts-api-giving-me-blank-mp3)
or this http://ctrlq.org/code/19147-text-to-speech-php

Comment: While this may work, the question does not mention using PHP. OP is looking to implement this in jQuery.